# window SRID does not match layer SRID

Tags: oracle, plsql, spatial

when running

```
select SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) dist into mdist
from ham_street h
WHERE SDO_NN(h.shape, mshape,'sdo_batch_size=1',1) = 'TRUE' and rownum = 1;
```

I get:

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-13208: internal error  while evaluating [window SRID does not match layer SRID] operator
ORA-06512: at "MSDGC.UPDATE_SSLATCLEANOUT_OFF_ROAD", line 64
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Both layer `Geometry SRID` and `MDSYS.USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA SRID` are blank. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my issue was. My layer I was updating did not have an SRID but the other layer i was referencing "HAM_STREET" had an SRID in MDSYS.USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA SRID. I deleted the SRID and now it works.